# Select2 change + AJAX leads to error

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, jquery-select2

I'm utilizing multiple Select2 fields for controlling data flow and selection for some forms. So, I have, for example, one Select2 disabled until another Select2 has an option selected in it. Once an option is chosen from the first Select2, I want to have an AJAX request that pulls information and adds it to the second Select2. I know what I have should work, but I'm getting the following error:

> Can only call HTMLFormElement.submit on instances of HTMLFormElement

The code is as follows:

```
$(document).on("change", "#business_unit", function (e) {
                e.preventDefault();

                $.ajax({
                        url: handler + "getUserGroupsForBusinessUnit",
                        type: "POST",
                        data: { businessUnit : $(this).val("id")},
                        success: function (response, textStatus, jqXHR) {
                                response = JSON.parse(response);
                                var option;

                                if (response.success) {
                                        swalTitle = successTitle;
                                        swalClass = success;

                                        $.each(response.userGroup, function (key, value) {
                                                option = new Option(value, key);
                                                $("#user_group").append(option);
                                        });

                                        $("#user_group").trigger("change");
                                        $("#user_group").prop("disabled", false);
                                } else {
                                        swalTitle = errorTitle;
                                        swalClass = error;
                                }

                                swal.close();

                                if (swalTitle == errorTitle) {
                                        displayInfoSWAL(swalTitle, response.message, swalClass);
                                }
                        },
                        beforeSend: function() {
                displayLoadingSWAL();
            },
                        error: function(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown){
                                console.error(
                                        "The following error occurred: "+
                                        textStatus, errorThrown
                                );
                        }
                });

                return false;
});
```

Comment: try `$(this).val()` instead of `$(this).val("id")`

Comment: Strange that I did not see that. When I tried it on my Desktop, I wasn't receiving the same error that I was on my laptop (Chrome vs Safari). It's fixed now, but I'll have to test on Safari later tonight.

Comment: Glad to know, it works. Let me add this as answer so that it help others too